# How to use javascript to change content value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently developing a system which user can only view the name with the start character.

Below is the example :

[image]

When I click on the "A" link, the below table will show the name which start from "A" and will not shows the rest of the records.

I am trying to use href to pass operation to my php but it is not flexible to do so. Therefore, I looking for javascript to help me go through this. What I want to do is the page will not refresh and will direct change the content when I click on the A~Z link.

This is my HTML code :

```
<li><a href="alumni-listing.php?op=a">A</a></li>
<li><a href="alumni-listing.php?op=b">B</a></li>
<li><a href="alumni-listing.php?op=c">C</a></li>
<li><a href="alumni-listing.php?op=d">D</a></li>
<li><a href="alumni-listing.php?op=e">E</a></li>
<li><a href="alumni-listing.php?op=f">F</a></li>
```

This is my php page which execute data from table :

```
        $rsa = array();
        $sqladded = false;
        $appliedfilter = array();
        if($_REQUEST['op'] = ''){
        $record = 'A';
        }
        else{
        $record = $_REQUEST['op'];
        }
        $stmt = $getuser->getuser($record);     

        if ($rs = $db->Execute($stmt))
        {
            $arrResult = array();
            while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow())
            {               
                array_push($arrResult, array(
                    "name" => $rsa['name'],
                    "mobile_no" => $rsa['mobile_no'],
                    "email" => $rsa['email'],
                    "address" => $rsa['address'],
                    "current_professional" => $rsa['current_professional'],
                    "others" => $rsa['others']
                    ));
            }           
            $tpl->display("alumni-listing.html");
        }
```

And this is my SQL statement :

```
function getuser($record)
    {
        global $db;
        $arrResult = array();

        $stmt = "SELECT * FROM "._CONST_TBL_ALUMNI." WHERE name LIKE ".$record."%";

        if($rs = $db->Execute($stmt))
        {
            $arrResult = $rs->GetArray();           
        }           
        return $arrResult;
    }
```

Hope someone can help me. 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Make separate divs for each of them, set all div's display to none. After on click of a particular link set display:block to the corresponding div

Comment: @shadow : how can I to do on which can return the value I want?

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow you have to use the calls to the PHP page.

If not then you can make a the 1st call load all data (A-Z) and then display the connects with just a click. But then your 1st call would be big and it will take time to load if data is greater.

You can use Ajax calls.

Structure your HTML as this way.

```
<li><a href="#" class='ajaxCaller>A</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='ajaxCaller>B</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='ajaxCaller>C</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='ajaxCaller>D</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='ajaxCaller>E</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='ajaxCaller>F</a></li>
```

The Ajax calls should be

```
  $('a.ajaxCaller').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var x=$(this).text();
     $.ajax({
       url: "alumni-listing.php",
       data: {op:x}
       }).done(function() {
           // You can have your code to set the returned page, to the specific div.
      });
 });
```

Comment: I am not really familiar to use ajax. but I have a question to ask which on the line "data:{op:x}". This value is pass from html page? Some more, inside "function(){}" the code I can write inside is sql statement or other else?

Comment: This code will call the PHP page "alumni-listing.php" and pass the parameter "op". "op" will have the values "A","B" which ever you click. Then that page will execute the sql statement and return you the HTML equivalent of that page. This is client side code you cannot have sql statements here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understood. But how can I return the result I want? Besides, there is no value pass from html. Therefore, how to get the value form html? Do I need to declare in some variable in html form like "name='a'" which pass from html to ajax?

Comment: var x=$(this).text(); Will get the value of the Tag clicked.
and data:{op:x} will pass that value to that url with parameter op

Answer (score 0):

So the way I see it, your problem boils down to dynamically querying the database on a Dom-event (i.e, through javascript) and not navigating to a different page. Which is lucky, because AJAX was developed pretty much for this - smaller 'refreshes'.

**Use JS to trigger a php request, and parse the return**

Check out jQuery's [Post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). I am sure it can be accomplished without, so please edit the question if jQuery is a no-no. If you change your php page to just echo a JSON of the result, and call if from JS, you can parse the JSON and display it in the html page.

HTML

`<li><a class="listing-filter" href="alumni-listing.php?op=a">A</a></li>
<li><a class="listing-filter" href="alumni-listing.php?op=b">B</a></li>
<li><a class="listing-filter" href="alumni-listing.php?op=c">C</a></li>
<li><a class="listing-filter" href="alumni-listing.php?op=d">D</a></li>
<li><a class="listing-filter" href="alumni-listing.php?op=e">E</a></li>
<li><a class="listing-filter" href="alumni-listing.php?op=f">F</a></li>`

Javascript

```
$('.listing-filter').click(function (e) {
  var $filter = $(e.currenttarget),
      filterValue = $filter.html();

  RefreshPageWithData(filterValue);
});

function RefreshPageWithData( filterBy ) {
 var data =  {
  op: filterBy,
 };
 $.post(pathname-on-server.php, data, function (response)  {
  //Parse the response
  var results = JSON.parse(response);

  //Construct the DOM
  var newHtml;

  //Append it to existing element
  $('#container').html(newHtml);
 });
```

Please note that *anything* you echo in the php page is the ***response*** passed back to the JS callback. So, a simple idea might be to `echo json_encode($arrResult)`. I suggest having one index.php that serves the file as you do above, and another that does similar tasks but echoes the retrieved data. This avoids a double-server request for the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I have made lots of project like the one you ask. Learning to use jQuery a javascript framework would be the best solution to solve the task. jQuery made ajax process very simple using [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: I am not clear and familiar about JQuery. Can you provide me a sample code?